# Why the name Bṛhadratha mentioned in Rig Veda 1.36.18? Does Bṛhadratha here mean legendary Bṛhadratha dynasty of Magadha?

Tags: mahabharata, vedas, rig-veda

> अग्निना तुर्वशं यदुं परावत उग्रादेवं हवामहे |
>  
>   अग्निर्नयन नववास्त्वं बर्हद्रथं तुर्वीतिं दस्यवे सहः || Rig Veda 1.36.18?

Meaning:

*We call on Ugradeva, Yadu, Turvaśa, by means of Agni, from afar;
Agni, bring Navavāstva and Bṛhadratha, Turvīti, to subdue the foe.*

Who is Bṛhadratha mentioned in the above verse? Is he the founder of Magadha dynasty?

Comment: In Gayatri Parivar translation, Navavastva, Barhadratha and Turveeti are referred as Rajarshi

Comment: Ajay pls.do also repeat the main question in Body section below the shlokas with some more explanation.This will further clarify what exactly do you want to ask and in which context etc.

Comment: @ Swift pushkar Bṛhadratha was a legendary dynasty that is believed to be ruled India in 3rd millennium BC. If that is mentioned Bṛhadratha was a legendary dynasty that could have to be ruled India in 3rd millennium BC. If that is mentioned in rig Veda, rig Veda might have composed after 3rd millennium BC.